# Can we remove impacted teeth by key hole surgery?

Tags: anatomy

Can we remove impacted teeth by key hole surgery, rather than an open technique, like lithotripsy?

Comment: Could you add some additional context to your question, such as what you know, why you are interested, etc.? It's not clear what you are seeking beyond a yes or no answer.

Answer (score 1):

The impacted tooth is partially or fully enclosed in the bone. Even if accessed by a drill hole to reach the tooth. The tooth is too hard to be cut up into smaller sections with any of the conventional equipments available through an endoscope.

Tooth is a composite of three highly organized, mineralised tissues. The bulk of the tooth is formed by dentin and has around 30% organic content almost similar to that of bone. A large part of the organic content is collagen a tough fibre. Where as kidney stones etc are aggregates of minerals etc and are much more susceptible for pulverisation by shock waves from a lithotripter.

Besides an impacted tooth is either partially of fully inclosed in bone. So that too rules out the use of a lithotripter.